# Is it possible to convert an irrational number into rational by using a different number system?

Tags: irrational-numbers, number-systems

It is certainly possible to convert a repeating number into a non repeating number by changing its number system. For example, 1÷3 is a repeating number in decimal as it equates to 0.3333333333.... However, if we use a base-3 number system, it becomes 0.1 which is a non repeating number. Thus, is it possible to do the same with irrational numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Irrational numbers are non-repeating decimals in any base.  A repeating decimal, or at least the tail part of it, can be recognized as a geometric series, and the formula for the sum of a geometric series shows it to be rational, whatever the base.